# Show a div onload, extend for 1 second, then fade out the same div and fade in the content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

How can I show a loading gif while the page is loading, make it show for 1 more second, then after the page is loaded and that 1 second has passed, the same loading gif will fade out and the main #content will fade in?

Edit: Thank you all for answering, I got it working! Here is the final product: http://invisiblelabs.net/wf/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<body>
    <div id="divload">
        <img src="loading.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="divcontent" style="visible: none">
       ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#divload').delay(1000).fadeOut();
    $('#divcontent').delay(1000).fadeIn();
});
```

First your gif will be visible and the content invisible. After the page is loaded and an additional 1 second delay the gif will fade out and the content will fade in.

Answer (score 0):

The quick/bad way to do it:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#content').fadeIn();
        $('#loading-image').fadeOut();
    },1000);
});
```

In modern browsers, there is a better way, which uses JavaScript for state toggling, along with CSS to do the actual animation.

Better Way (css, part 1):

```
#content{ opacity:0 }
#loading-image{ opacity:1; }    
#content, #loading-image
{
    -webkit-animation:opacity 1s 1s;
    /* Note... example only specifies Webkit.  You should do the same for -moz, -ms, etc*/
}
body.loaded #loading-image { opacity:0;}
body.loaded #content {opacity:1}
```

Better Way (js, part 2):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
});
```

Comment: How to fade in #loading when you access the page? (not when it is fully loaded)